# How do I use tr command to replace: full stops, exclamations and question marks followed by a space, with newlines?

Tags: text-processing, tr

I have text that goes like this:

```
I am happy. I am here. How are you, Meg?
```

I want this to be:

```
I am happy.
I am here.
How are you, Meg?
```

For full stops I tried

```
tr -s '. ' '\n' <file.txt >out.txt
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know `tr` only works with single characters and *". "* is a string not a character, so it is possible to do what you want by using `sed` or `awk`, for example:

```
sed -e "s/\. /\n/g" file.txt > out.txt
```

Comment: He said *use tr*.

Comment: @argle Well, he can't.

Comment: I know. I just didn't realize xy answers were allowed even against explicit constraints. This could have been my answer. So I was protesting. :P

Answer (score 14):

You don't.  `tr` is not designed for that. It's designed to transliterate a set of *single characters* into another set of *single characters*, e.g., `A-Z` into `a-z`. Using `tr` with `.␣` (a dot and a space) and `\n` will replace all dots and spaces with newlines.

Use (GNU) `sed` instead:

```
$ echo 'I am happy. I am here. How are you, Meg?' | sed 's/\([!.?]\) /\1\n/g'
I am happy.      
I am here.       
How are you, Meg?
```

The `sed` editing script here will replace all occurrences of `!`, `.` or `?` that are followed by a space, by the same character and a newline.

Comment: I'd like to emphasize _single characters_ since OP seems to believe `tr` will replace TWO characters `'. '` with just one character `'\n'` - Instead  `tr` replaces both `'.'` _**and**_ `' '` with `'\n'`.

Comment: @Yanevski Emphasis added.

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned , you can't achieve what you want with `tr` due to the nature of `tr`. But there are many other alternatives. For instance, Python 2.

As one-liner we could do this:

```
python -c "import sys;print '\n'.join([ j.strip() for l in sys.stdin.readlines() for j in  l.rstrip().split('.')])" < input.txt
```

As a script , it would be like so:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

sentences = []
for line in sys.stdin:
    for sentence in line.rstrip().split('.'):
        sentences.append(sentence.strip())

print "\n".join(sentences)
```

And used as so:

```
$ ./split_to_lines.py  < input.txt                                                                    
I am happy
I am here
How are you, Meg?
```

Nothing particularly complex is going on here - we're merely splitting all lines in file into sentences at `.` and then strip leading and trailing space for each sentence. All that goes into a list, which is then reassembled via `.join()`  function.